# Can I recover lost data after formatting Mac HD?

Tags: macos

I lost my private keys after formatting my Mac and reinstalling my OS. I only have the public keys and the passphrase. What can I do?

Comment: It is not possible to restore a private key from a public key, no matter if passphrase is known or not.

Comment: Are you trying to recover files on this disk? Surely "formatting" would have destroyed all files on it anyway? Do you not have a backup?

Comment: @benwiggy Formatting doesn't necessarily delete the files in hard disk (depending on the options used) - it just marks the space occupied by any data as 'empty'. But if you write any new data on the formatted disk, old files on it can be overwritten and thus become unrecoverable.

Comment: @sfxedit Yes, but either way, your intention is to clear the disk. Why would you format a disk if it was your only copy? Or, if you don't need to recover any data, why does recovering the keys matter?

Comment: @benwiggy Mistakes happen. You might have thought you have backed up all the important files before formatting a disk, but then realised that the one file you needed was in some other folder that you didn't backup. Anyway, I was clarifying your doubt whether formatting would have destroyed all the files - as LSerni explained in his answer, the data may be still be there even after formatting the drive. (The type of drive also matters - I think it easier to recover data from HDD than SSD).

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, it is currently **impossible** (rather: computationally unfeasible) to recreate the private keys from the public keys (otherwise they wouldn't be "private", and public keys wouldn't be, as they are, safely discloseable to all and sundry). The passphrase is just an encryption of the private keys, and while required for their recovery, it is not *per se* sufficient - you still need the encrypted private keys.

There is, perhaps, some small hope of recovering said encrypted private keys from the formatted disk, since *formatting* is not the same thing as *erasing*. The private keys are small and their format is distinctive, so **if they have not been overwritten** by the OS reinstalled files, it is possible they're not only still lying somewhere in the free space of the disk, but they're in a single, recognizable and thus recoverable fragment.

The disk must be set off line as soon as possible to prevent further writes to increase the risk of overwriting the data, and the free area examined with forensic tools by an expert or at least someone familiar with the mechanics of this undertaking. The operation can take several hours depending on the hard disk size.

If the disk has been already filled with data, or worse, a "secure erase", "secure format", "diagnostic rewrite", or similar operation has been performed prior to the reinstallation, then recovery chances are nil - that's literally the point of a "secure erase". Sorry.

Comment: Good answer - perhaps you can suggest some data recovery software on macOS that they can try to search and recover the keys?